# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: Models.Users

Tags: java, hibernate

**I have viewed the related questions, but still don't find the answer to fix my error.**

This is my project structure:

```
 - src
  - java
   - HibernateDemo
     - HibernateTestApplication.java
     - HibernateUtil.java
   - Models
     - Users.java
   - res
     - hibernate.cfg.xml
     - Users.hbm.xml
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">***</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <!--<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>-->

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <!--<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>-->

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->

        <mapping resource="Users.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my Users.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Models.Users" table="users">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the users detail.
        </meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
        <property name="age" column="age" type="int"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my Users.java:

```
package Models;

public class Users {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Users(){}

    public Users(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

This is my HibernateUtil.java:

```
package HibernateDemo;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import java.io.File;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static HibernateUtil instance = null;

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private HibernateUtil(){
        String hibernatePropsFilePath = "E:\\java workspace\\study\\hibernate\\src\\main\\java\\res\\hibernate.cfg.xml";
        File hibernatePropsFile = new File(hibernatePropsFilePath);

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure(hibernatePropsFile);
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    public static HibernateUtil getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance  = new HibernateUtil();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

This is my HibernateTestApplication.java:

```
package HibernateDemo;

import Models.Users;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class HibernateTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateTestApplication hibernateTestApplication = new HibernateTestApplication();
        int userId = hibernateTestApplication.addUser("Tom", 21);
        System.out.println(userId);
    }

    public int addUser(String name, int age){
        HibernateUtil hibernateUtil = HibernateUtil.getInstance();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        int userId = 0;

        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Users user = new Users(name, age);
            userId = (Integer) session.save(user);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return userId;
    }
}
```

**I hope you can patiently read the code above, and find the real problem to my code, thx!**

Comment: Just a thought: having a capital M in package name "Models" is not conventional (should be all lowercase). Change that everywhere.

Comment: Pls share the exception stacktrace for more clarity on the origin of the issue.

Comment: Another thought: could you please check that your "Users.hbm.xml" is in the classpath (e.g. with Maven then it should be copied into 'target', if it's old fashioned eclipse then perhaps 'bin' directory, etc)? Because it's not customary to place ".xml" files under 'java' as you did, *but* it might be ok depending on your IDE/build tool...

Comment: @PelitMamani, thank you for your comment! I have solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the class mapping for Users in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

The Hibernate configuration file must define the entity classes:

```
<mapping class="Models.Users"/>
```

Comment: I add `<mapping class="Models.Users"/>` .It's not working

Answer (score 0):

When you give the mapping resources, give the absolute path in this format:

`<mapping resource="res/Users.hbm.xml"`/>

If it was mapping via class names, (*when class it resolves as package name*)
`<mapping class="Models.Users"`/>

As above didn't work, please try building session factory like this:

```
protected static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure("/res/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addResource("res/Users.hbm.xml")
                .buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed" + ex);
    }
}
```

See if this loads correct. This uses the current class path to resolve as opposed to loading hbm file from filesystem.

Comment: 1. I have tried `<mapping resource="res/Users.hbm.xml"/>`, it's not working. And Why mapping resources can not use relative path?  2.I annotate the mapping resource, and use the mapping via class names like you wrote above. It's not working neither, still the same MappingException

Comment: I have solved my question using @PelitMamani method! I add the two xml files to my target folder, and the exception is gone. Forgive me for being novice in Maven. Thank you all again!